# Looping through associative array not as expected

Tags: zsh

According to the recipe described in [Associative arrays in zsh](https://scriptingosx.com/2019/11/associative-arrays-in-zsh/), I tried the following script to test a loop through an associative Array in Zsh 5.5.1:

```
typeset -A emap
emap=( X y U v )
for key val in ${(kv)emap}
do
  echo key=$key val=$val
done
```

I get the expected output

```
key=U val=v
key=X val=y
```

But when I write the example like this:

```
env_code ()
{
  typeset -A emap
  emap=( MX1 Mme VOX Vbo MS1 Msc JRUBY_VERSION '()' FOO '')
  local ename
  local abbr
  for ename abbr in ${(kv)emap}
  do
    echo ename=$ename abbr=$abbr
  done
}
env_code # Invoking the function
```

I get the output

```
ename=FOO abbr=JRUBY_VERSION
ename=() abbr=MX1
ename=Mme abbr=MS1
ename=Msc abbr=VOX
ename=Vbo abbr=
```

We see that keys and values are exchanged. I would have expected the output

```
ename=MX1 abbr=Mme
ename=VOX abbr=Vbo
```

Comment: Not just exchanged: entirely scrambled.

Comment: @chepner : I think the order is not determined in an associative array, because also in the first example, I get it in different order than entered.

Comment: The order of the key-value pairs is arbitrary, but each key should remain associated with the value immediately following it. The problem is with the expansion, though, not the array itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array itself is intact:

```
% typeset -A emap
% emap=( MX1 Mme VOX Vbo MS1 Msc JRUBY_VERSION '()' FOO '')
% declare -p emap
typeset -A emap=( [FOO]='' [JRUBY_VERSION]='()' [MS1]=Msc [MX1]=Mme [VOX]=Vbo)
```

Note, in particular, the *order* of the key-value pairs.

However, when you expand `${(kv)emap}` without quotes, the empty string value of the key `FOO` is lost.

```
% print -l ${(kv)emap}
FOO
JRUBY_VERSION
()
MX1
Mme
MS1
Msc
VOX
Vbo
```

As a result, `FOO` is "mapped" to the value `JRUBY_VERSION`, not `''`.

Quoting the expansion restores the expected behavior. With quotes, you need the explicit indexing operation to produce individual arguments to `print`.

```
% print -l "${(kv)emap[@]}"
FOO

JRUBY_VERSION
()
MX1
Mme
MS1
Msc
VOX
Vbo
```

Without `[@]`, the empty string is still preserved, just harder to notice.

```
% print -l "${(kv)emap}"
FOO  JRUBY_VERSION () MX1 Mme MS1 Msc VOX Vbo

# Note the two spaces between FOO and JRUBY_VERSION.
```

Unquoted parameter expansions are not subject to word splitting, but they *are* subject to quote removal, and with *no* characters remaining after the quotes are removed from the empty string, there is no argument left after the expansion.

Comment: Good explanation, except for _Unquoted parameter expansions are not subject to word splitting_ . This would be correct for bash or ksh, where word splitting occurs **after** parameter expansion in scalar variables, but nor for Zsh, at least not for **scalar variables**, where you would have to request word splitting explicitly. I think this is then called _interpolation_ in Zsh. But I think, with arrays there is (for compatibility to ksh) likely a difference between `$arr` and `$arr[@]` and `"$arr[@]"`. I will have to read up about this topic for the safe side.

Comment: I stand by the wording: you don't have to quote parameter expansions to *prevent* word-splitting, since it isn't applied in the first case. `$arr` still expands to distinct *words*, even if each word isn't subject to further word-splitting (consider `arr=("a b" c); print -l $arr`), but `"$arr"` is  a *single* word, while `"${arr[@]}"` is again two separate words.

Comment: I see the argument! But I don't see the difference (in your example) beween using `foo $arr` and `foo "${arr[@]}"` for some program _foo_. In both cases, as I could reproduce, _foo_ is called with two parameters (`a b` and `c`). Therefore I wonder why we need the usage if `@` in my case - and we **do** need it, as I can experimentally verify.

Comment: There is no difference. But if you quote `$arr` *without* indexing, you get `a b c` as a single line of output.